# Cant see local disk in oracle linux installation to dual boot windows 7 and oracle linux

Tags: windows-7, linux, partitioning, multi-boot, oracle-linux

Iam trying to dual boot windows 7(already running Windows7) and oracle linux 7 with bootable USB Stick. First I downloaded Oracle Linux Release 7 for x86_64 (64 Bit) V46135-01.iso from https://edelivery.oracle.com/osdc/faces/SearchSoftware then I created a partition of 50 GB (FAT32) for Oracle Linux then I created a bootable USB Stick using Rufus 2.11.exe on windows OS. after that I started the installation from USB Stick but To choose where to **install the Linux the partition of 50GB I made earlier is not listed** [plz check this pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBFx0.jpg)

Comment: Probably it's not needed to format the partition to fat32, but just let free some space. Because Linux usually use ext-filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem is very easy. Probably when you made a new 50GB Fat32 partition at that time you haven't formatted it. You should also make sure that you haven't left that 50gb unallocated.

So you can now solve the problem by booting into Windows7 and then formatting it again or you can also try to format it as NTFS for troubleshooting.